# eclipse logcat displays incorrect information

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I'm not sure why, but ever since I updated android-SDK and Eclipse ADT to the latest versions, the logcat view in Eclipse has begun malfunctioning.

[image: eclipse logcat bug]

As you can see, `adb logcat` shows me correct output whereas Eclipse logcat does not.

I have tried the following with no luck.

- Reconnecting phone
- Restarting eclipse
- `adb kill-server`

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse IDE in general is not perfect. Use the `adb logcat` command in terminal